# Changing img source onmouseover using only javascript and 'this'

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to change img src attribute to src matching another picture on site which user hovered over. I have 1 (main) picture and I have 3 below it (sub), acting as a gallery. When user hovers over one of those 3, I want src attribute of main to change to src of sub image. 
All resolutions I found so far, use either 1 image whose source is changed in code or only specific sources declared but I don't want to add sources in code every time a new image is added, instead, using i.e. gallery(this) for each sub-image should resolve it but I'm having no luck so far.
Apologies if there is same question, I just couldn't find it. If this explanation is too complicated, feel free to ask, I'm looking forward resolving this, if possible.

Tried to use `function name(this)` to exploit source of image and add it to main picture.
I'm really just starting with all of this so this what I tried so far probably isn't even close enough, hope you will understand.

```html
  <img class="hover" src="imgs/mountain.jpg" id="hover" alt="">
      <div class="imgs">
        <img onmouseover="gallery(this)" src="imgs/castle.jpg" alt="">
        <img onmouseover="gallery(this)" src="imgs/mountain.jpg" alt="">
        <img onmouseover="gallery(this)" src="imgs/tree.jpg" alt="">
      </div>

    <script>
        function gallery(element) {
            x = document.getElementById('hover');
            x.src.element;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Changing image src value works, but it's often less ideal because of the delay in loading after the change than just loading all of the images and giving all but one (css) `display:hidden`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't actually changing the `src`. You can do so by setting `x.src` to `element.src`:

```js
function gallery(element) {
  x = document.getElementById('hover');
  x.src = element.src;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgs">
  <img onmouseover="gallery(this)" src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=1" alt="">
  <img onmouseover="gallery(this)" src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=2" alt="">
  <img onmouseover="gallery(this)" src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=3" alt="">
</div>
<img id="hover" alt="hover">
```

Comment: x.src = element.src;

This actually saved the day. Thank you kind sir.

Comment: @nickelodeon No worries. If you ever need more help, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

As Kobe states in their answer, to set the src you can use `img.src = {source}`.

I would recommend that you add event listeners to each image, rather than using attributes to call the function. This provides a much cleaner solution. I have added the `.gallery` class to each image, then, it loops through these elements adding the event listener.

```js
function displayImage() {
  x.src = this.src;
}

// Pull this out of the function to avoid the lookup every time
var x = document.getElementById('hover');

// Loop through each element with the gallery class and add the event listener
document.querySelectorAll(".gallery").forEach(function(img) {
  img.addEventListener("mouseover", displayImage);
});
```

```html
<div class="imgs">
  <img class="gallery" src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=1" alt="">
  <img class="gallery" src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=2" alt="">
  <img class="gallery" src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=3" alt="">
</div>
<img id="hover" alt="hover">
```

Comment: I would say this is cleaner, but, it takes more effort, which can be confusing for a beginner. It would make sense to use an event listener for many elements, but here I think the `onmouseover` event works better on each element, since there's only 3 elements. I removed my alts and put actual images now :) Nonetheless your solution works 

Comment: Ah, looks much better with actual images! Thanks @Kobe I thought I would include a solution making use of `addEventListener` as it may be useful for any future visitors.

Comment: Thank you both but Kobe's answer was exactly the thing I was looking for, since I'm a beginner and this was for training purposes. Probably down the road, second answer will make more sense. Anyways, nicely done indeed. Case closed.